# SQL 'IN' operator in lambda

Tags: c#, lambda

devs. Got next fast question.

It's about good practice.

```
ListA.Where(x => (x.Name == "James Bond") || (x.Number == "007" || x.Number == "7"));
```

Im looking for James Bond or Agent with number 007 or 7.

//Some fun

Well, in this example Im looking only for 2 numbers.
Is there any way in lambda expresion similar to IN operator in SQL?

i.e

```
string[] nums = {"007","7"};
ListA.Where(x => (x.Name == "James Bond") || (x.Number.Contains(nums));
```

Comment: Just swap the last clause, ie. nums.Contains(x.Number).

Comment: @bobblez - post it as answer and earn your points )

Comment: bobblez was the first person who post it as a comment and the other users copy it and paste as an answer. Not fair! )

Comment: Thats true. bobblez post it ;)

Comment: @VoonArt - if its true - unmark your question as an answer and wait till boolez post it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
string[] nums = {"007","7"};
ListA.Where(x => (x.Name == "James Bond") || (nums.Contains(x.Number));
```

Answer (score 4):

```
ListA.Where(x => (x.Name == "James Bond") || nums.Contains(x.Number));
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
ListA.Where(x => (x.Name.Equals("James Bond")) || nums.Contains(x.Number));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
string[] nums = {"007","7"};//Array of numbers to be checked

ListA.Where(x => (x.Name == "James Bond") || (nums.Contains(x.Number);
```